# sed: strip enclosing square brackets

Tags: sed, string, replace

I have this file:

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
output = json
[profile automation]
region = us-east-1
output = json
[profile qa]
region = us-east-1
output = json
```

I need to extract only the profile names like so:

```
default
automation
qa
```

My sed so far:

```
gsed 's?\[[^\ ]*\ \([^\]]*\)?\1?' ~/.aws/config
```

As I'm testing, I can see that `\([^\]]*\)` matches only the first character after the space for example: the `a` in `automation`, the `q` in qa etc..
Why it only matches once?
Do you have a better way of stripping the `[]`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A backslash inside a bracketed expression is literal.  You want `[^]]`.  Your expression `[^\]]*` would match a non-backslash followed by an optional `]`.

```
$ sed -En 's/^\[(.* )?([^]]*)\]$/\2/p' file
default
automation
qa
```

This allows for optional words terminated by a space as the first substring inside `[...]`, e.g. `[group name]`. The string after these optional words, up to the `]`, is captured in the second group.

The default printing of every line is turned off with `-n` and instead we print explicitly after each successful substitution.

We need `-E` since the `?` modifier is an extended regular expression modifier.

Without `-E` you could use `\{0,1\}` in place of the `?` (and change the capturing `(` and `)` into `\(` and `\)` respectively).

Comment: BREs have `\{0,1\}` as the equivalent of ERE `?`, so you don't have to use that non-standard `-E` here.

Comment: Why don't I have to escape the `]`? Why is it not treated as the end of the group?

Comment: @Moshe If `]` occurs as the first character in the group, or as the first after `^`, it will not end the group.

Comment: @Kusalananda this was the missing part! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `grep` or compatible built with PCRE support:

```
grep -Po '^\h*\[\h*(\H+\h+)?\K.*[^]\h](?=\h*\]\s*$)'
```

We allow leading horizontal whitespace sometimes found for indentation and trailing whitespace, including vertical for the CR character generally found in MS Windows ini files.

On an input like:

```
[default]
[profile automation]
[profile a  b]
[profile  c d ]
```

It gives:

```
default
automation
a  b
c d
```